# Selecting rows from a column which name is in a variable

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I have a dataset with a named column. The name of the column is also in a variable. I would like to be able to select all rows that satisfy a condition on the column "col".

Here I would like to select all rows whose value in the "col" column matches the condition "< 2".

```
name = "col"
dataset = data.frame(col = 1:3)
```

I tried to use "eval" in subset, or the "select" function of the dplyr package, but it does not do what I want (or I misused it).

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Try: `dataset[ dataset[[ name ]] < 2, ]`

Comment: Why not just reference the column number rather than the name?

Comment: I would like to create a function and let the user decide the file structure to pass. Thus I don't know name nor the column number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're new(ish) to R, I'm going to recommend using the `tidyverse` set of packages, including the ever-useful `dplyr` for problems like this so you can have more immediately readable and understandable code. You can get this package using `install.packages('tidyverse')`. With that installed, to answer your question:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  col = c(0:10),
  another_col = c(10:20),
  third_col = c(25:35)
)

dynamic_name <- "col"

filter_at(df, dynamic_name, ~ .x < 2)
```

Note: The `tidyverse` family of packages typically accept the formula syntax (that `~` expression) as a way to introduce anonymous (lambda) functions, so `~ .x < 2` is a function that returns `TRUE` if the value passed in is less than 2).

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, I'm new to R and learning on my own so many useful packages slip by.
'filter_at' is said to be superseded in the documentation, do you know how to do the same thing using 'accross' (which is apparently the new function to use, if I understood correctly)?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it too much. `across()` is *very* new and I wouldn't expect the *_at, *_if, *_all functions to go away any time soon. If you're looking for learning materials, there's some really good (mostly free) stuff here: https://rstudio.com/resources/books/

Answer (score 0):

please see below.

```
a <- 1:5
b <- 6:10
namevar <- "a"
df <- data.frame(a,b)
df[df[,namevar] %in% c(1:3),]
  a b
1 1 6
2 2 7
3 3 8
```

What happens here is that `df[,namevar] %in% c(1:3)` gives a vector of `TRUE`, `FALSE` depending on whether the condition is met.

Then passing this boolean vector as indices to `df` yields all the rows where the condition is `TRUE`.

For more details about `%in%` see `help(is.element())`